# Get last tuesday in month ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

Can get last weekday in the month through NSDateComponents? For example: last monday in month or last friday in month. etc

Comment: I don't think so, but it's pretty easy to write a method. Algorithm would be something like: `given month m, d = lastDayInMonth(m), while(notWeekday(d)) d--;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution; tested, and fairly robust, I think.
We'll let NSCalendar walk through the month, a day at a time, and pull out all matching weekdays as NSDates. Then you can answer questions like, "The 3rd Wednesday of this month"

I believe the comments are clear about what is happening, and why.
If you need further clarification, I'll be happy to do so.

```
//What weekday are we interested in? 1 = Sunday . . . 7 = Saturday
NSInteger targetWeekday = 1;

//Using this methodology, GMT timezone is important to set
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
calendar.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];

//set the components to the first of the current month
NSDateComponents *startComponents = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];
startComponents.day = 1;

//the enumeration starts "afterDate", so shift the start back one day (86400 seconds) to include the 1st of the month
NSDate *startDate = [[calendar dateFromComponents:startComponents] dateByAddingTimeInterval:-86400];

//the enumeration searches for a match; we'll match at the midnight hour and find every occurance of midnight
NSDateComponents *dayByDay = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
dayByDay.hour = 0;

//I've opted to put all matching weekdays of the month into an array, so you can find any instance easily
__block NSMutableArray *foundDates = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:5];
[calendar enumerateDatesStartingAfterDate:startDate
                       matchingComponents:dayByDay
                                  options:NSCalendarMatchPreviousTimePreservingSmallerUnits
                               usingBlock:^(NSDate *date, BOOL exactMatch, BOOL *stop){
                                   NSDateComponents *thisComponents = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:date];
                                   //as long as the month stays the same... (or the year, if you wanted to)
                                   if (thisComponents.month == startComponents.month) {

                                       //does this date match our target weekday search?
                                       if (thisComponents.weekday == targetWeekday) {

                                           //then add it to our result array
                                           [foundDates addObject:date];
                                       }

                                   //once the month has changed, we're done
                                   } else {
                                       *stop = YES;
                                   }
                               }];

//Now, with our search result array, we can find the 1st, last, or any specific occurance of that weekday on that month
NSLog(@"Found these: %@", foundDates);
```

So, if you only wanted the last one, then just use [foundDates lastObject]

Comment: Great, glad it helps :)

Answer (score 3):

Just another way to solve. Find the first day of the next month, then search backwards for Tuesday.

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let today = NSDate()
let components = calendar.components([.Year, .Month], fromDate: today)
components.month += 1

// If today is 2016-07-12 then nextMonth will be the 
// first day of the next month: 2016-08-01
if let nextMonth = calendar.dateFromComponents(components) {
    // Search backwards for weekday = Tuesday
    let options: NSCalendarOptions = [.MatchPreviousTimePreservingSmallerUnits, .SearchBackwards]
    calendar.nextDateAfterDate(nextMonth, matchingUnit: .Weekday, value: 3, options: options)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. This works for me.

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comps = [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
int weekday = [comps weekday];
int lastTues;
int lastSatDay;
if (weekday==1) {
    lastTues=5;
    lastSatDay=1;
}
else if (weekday==2)
{
    lastTues=6;
    lastSatDay=2;
}
else if (weekday==3)
{
    lastTues=7;
    lastSatDay=3;
}
else if (weekday==4)
{
    lastTues=1;
    lastSatDay=4;
}
else if (weekday==5)
{
    lastTues=2;
    lastSatDay=5;
}
else if (weekday==6)
{
    lastTues=3;
    lastSatDay=6;
}
else if (weekday==7)
{
    lastTues=4;
    lastSatDay=7;
}

NSDate *lastTuesDay = [[NSDate date] addTimeInterval:-3600*24*(lastTues)];
NSDate *lastSaturday = [[NSDate date] addTimeInterval:-3600*24*(lastSatDay)];
```

Comment: If I want to know last saturday What should I Write. @stanly Moses

Comment: see the updated code...accept if it answers else revert back and i will help you to sort out the issue.

Comment: It is giving coming Saturday not giving last saturday @Stanly Moses

Comment: what do you mean by giving coming?

Comment: It is Showing like last saturday is»»»»  2016-07-01 09:17:21 +0000

Comment: I have same result: 2016-07-01, must be 2016-06-25